# User Defined Exceptions with JMX

Tags: java, exception, jmx

I have exposed methods for remote management in my application server using JMX by creating an MXBean interface, and a class to implement it. Included in this interface are operations for setting attributes on my server, and for getting the current value of attributes. For example, take the following methods:

```
public interface WordManagerMXBean {
     public void addWord(String word);
     public WordsObject getWords();
     public void removeWord(String word);
}
```

The WordsObject is a custom, serializable class used to retrieve data about the state of the server. Then I also have a WordManager class that implements the above interface. I then create a JMX agent to manage my resource:

```
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName wordManagerName = new ObjectName("com.example:type=WordManager");
mbs.registerMBean(wordManager, wordManagerName);
```

I have created a client that invokes these methods, and this works as expected. However, I would like to extend this current configuration by adding user defined exceptions that can be sent back to my client. So I would like to change my interface to something like this:

```
public interface WordManagerMXBean {
     public void addWord(String word) throws WordAlreadyExistsException;
     public WordsObject getWords();
     public void removeWord(String word);
}
```

My WordAlreadyExistsException looks like this:

```
public class WordAlreadyExistsException extends Exception implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9095552123119275304L;

public WordAlreadyExistsException() {
    super();
    }
}
```

When I call the addWord() method in my client, I would like to get back a WordAlreadyExistsException if the word already exists. However, when I do this, I get an error like this:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.WordAlreadyExistsException
```

The WordAlreadyExistsException, the WordsObject and the WordManagerMXBean interface are all in a single jar file that is available to both the client and the server. If I call the getWords() method, the client has no difficulty handling the WordsObject. However, if a user defined exception, like the one above, is thrown, then the client gives the error shown above. Is it possible to configure JMX to handle this exception correctly in the client?

Following some searching, I noticed that there is an MBeanException class that is used to wrap exceptions. I'm not sure if this wrapping is performed by the agent automatically, or if I'm supposed to do the wrapping myself. I tried both, but in either case I get the same error on the client.

I have also tried this with both checked and unchecked exceptions, again the same error occurs.

One solution to this is to simply pass back the error string inside a generic error, as all of the standard java exceptions work. But I'd prefer to get back the actual exception for processing by the client.

Is it possible to handle user defined exceptions in JMX? If so, any ideas how?

EDIT: Including full stack trace

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at $Proxy4.addWord(Unknown Source)
at com.example.TestClient.addWord(TestClient.java:76)
at com.example.TestClient.execute(TestClient.java:56)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.WordAlreadyExistsException
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:245)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1017)
at  javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:305)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.WordAlreadyExistsException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:453)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:184)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:216)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:243)
... 11 more
```

Comment: you're _sure_ that class exists in the client classloader?  you aren't running with an old jar or something?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I confirmed this by modifying my WordsObject class to contain an extra field, rebuilding the jar, and replacing the existing jar file with the new one. When I ran the client again, I could get the new field in the WordsObject, but I still get the same error with the exception.

Comment: did you visually inspect the contents of the jar to confirm that the class is there and in the correct package?

Comment: Yes. I can confim that the jar file contains the class file for the WordAlreadyExistsException.

Comment: can you include the full stacktrace of the exception (at least inside jdk code)?

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the full stack trace.

Comment: Extract from the Java Management Extensions (JMX )Specification, The MBeanException also wraps the actual exception
defined by the user and thrown by an MBean method. This to me suggests that "Any exception thrown by an MBean" can be wrapped and passed to the mxbean client. Anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: Just to be certain - are you using Java 1.6 or Java 1.7?

Comment: @JoeG I'm using Java 1.7

Comment: @PaulWhelan - that is my understanding

Comment: For testing, could you add a method that *returns* your custom exception instead of throwing it (eg. public WordAlreadyExistsException createException()) and test if the custom exception was successfully unmarshaled?

Comment: Another way of tracking this down is to attach a debugger to your server and set a breakpoint on RMIClassLoader.loadClass() and check how the class loader hierarchy is traversed when trying to load your class. (In eclipse, you can add a conditional breakpoint that only stops when your class is attempted to be loaded) This could become cumbersome, but it might help to figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem, however it works fine for me ;-(. See the exception output below. I also would bet, that it is really a class loading issue on the client side. Is it possible that you could post (a stripped down) version of your client jar (and maybe the source as well) ?

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.management.MBeanException: WordAlreadyExistsException
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.unwrapInvocationTargetException(MBeanIntrospector.java:283)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:210)
.....
Caused by: WordAlreadyExistsException
at WordManager.addWord(WordManager.java:7)
.....
```

Comment: Your assumption about it being a class loading issue on the client side is correct. For my client, I was using clamshell-cli framework, which uses a plugin architecture based on the ServiceLoader api. My jar file is a plugin to clamshell. So although my jar file contains the exception, this class does not seem to be loaded. I then added the jar file to a lib directory in clamshell as well. After doing this, the class seems to have been loaded correctly, and the exception is thrown as desired.

Comment: It seems strange that my WordsObject was being loaded correctly since it was in the same package, but the issue is now resolved in any case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening is that your custom exception is serialized and then deserialized back within the application server but in different, for the lack of a better word, "classloader namespace".

Try placing the jar(c) containing the custom exception classes together with your JMX jars that the AppServer is using. Make sure you remove the old jars from the old location (I am assuming it's somewhere in WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to throw custom exceptions, although not recommended. From [JMX Best practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/best-practices-jsp-136021.html#mozTocId730341):

> It is recommended that exceptions thrown by MBeans be drawn from the
>   standard set defined in the java.* and javax.* packages on the Java SE
>   platform. If an MBean throws a non-standard exception, a client that
>   does not have that exception class will likely see another exception
>   such as ClassNotFoundException instead.

Therefore, I would put some money that your client simply didn't load the `WordAlreadyExistsException` class. You can check that rather simple - write a method **in the client** that throws this exception, invoke it and see what happens. If everything went OK (OK = custom exception was thrown, no `ClassNotFoundException`) then make sure that your client and server have same version of jar that contains `WordAlreadyExistsException`. Even the slightest mismatch (for example, in the package name) can be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception must be extending from

```
    javax.management.JMException
```

or

```
    javax.management.JMRuntimeException
```

in case it is a RuntimeException.

Comment: I have tried extending both MBeanException and RuntimeMBeanException. These extend javax.management.JMException and javax.management.JMRuntimeException. The same error occurs when I do this. Have you had some success doing this?

Comment: I didn't get the exception when I have the classes in place. I strongly doubt that its CLASSPATH or your Jar doesn't have the class.

Comment: @user1802492 My answer is meant to clarify that JMX implementations must be throwing JMException or JMRuntimeException. It can be either by extending or wrapping.

Comment: @Daniel - Can you try changing your interface as MXBean and throw the exception? Maybe, if its able to get the exception in your client side, we can be sure that it is not a problem with your class but the presence of your class file in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending RuntimeMBeanException ,Just pass your RuntimeException as constructor argument for RuntimeMBeanException and throws that exception. Ensure that jar files are present in the CLASSPATH.

Extending RuntimeMBeanException may also work provided the the jar file is present in class path but I didn't test that

Comment: This was one of the things that I have tried. I still get the same error when I do this. You seem to suggest that you have got this working. Would you be able to provide more detail about this, or perhaps post a working example of this?

Comment: I have tested this with jConsole. i copied the jar file to \jre\lib\ext folder and it worked. It will throw java.rmi.UnmarshalException if the jar file is not copied to \jre\lib\ext folder